# apache2: ERROR: Module not properly enabled

Tags: apache, apache2, a2enmod

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: Module wsgi not properly enabled:
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load is a real file, not touching it

I have this:

```
USER root
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN a2enmod wsgi
```

does anyone know what this error would signify?
I can't figure out how to resolve it.

if I forgo the `a2enmod wsgi` line, then I get:

> /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the file or directory mod_wsgi.so doesn't exist on your server. You may follow the instructions below on how to enable this module.

1. SSH to your machine.
2. Once you'r logged in, please execute the following commands below:

$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

$ sudo a2enmod wsgi

3. Please execute the find command to locate the mod_wsgi.so module.

$ sudo find / -name *mod_wsgi.so

You should see this result.

/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

Furthermore, to install apache2 please execute the command below:

$ sudo apt-get install apache2 -y

Hope this information works for you.